# Prove by induction: $2!\cdot 4!\cdot 6!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2n)!\ge ((n+1)!)^n$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Prove by induction: $2!\cdot 4!\cdot 6!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2n)!\ge ((n+1)!)^n$

For $n=1$ inequality holds.

$(*)$For $n=k$

$2!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2k)!\ge ((k+1)!)^k$

Multiplying LHS and RHS with $(2k+2)!$ gives

$$2!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2k)!(2k+2)!\ge ((k+1)!)^k(2k+2)!$$

Assume (by contradiction)$$2!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2k)!(2k+2)!< ((k+1)!)^k(2k+2)!$$
$$2!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2k)!(2k+2)!-((k+1)!)^k(2k+2)!<0$$
$$(2k+2)!(2!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2k)!-((k+1)!)^k)<0$$

$(2!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2k)!-((k+1)!)^k)\ge 0$ by $(*)$, thus inequality holds $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: When attempting a proof by induction, one *assumes* that the inductive hypothesis is true. What you have essentially done is said, assuming that the IH is true, the IH can't be false. You haven't actually proven anything here.

Comment: It might be easier to show that $(n+1+k)!(n+1-k)! \ge (n+1)!^2$ for $0 \le k \le n-1$ since $n+1+m \ge n+1-m$ for $0 \le m \le k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{1}(2k)!\geq(1+1)!^{1}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}(2k)!\geq(n+1)!^{n}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}(2k)!=$

$\color\red{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}(2k)!}\cdot(2(n+1))!\geq$

$\color\red{(n+1)!^{n}}\cdot(2(n+1))!=$

$(n+1)!^{n}\cdot(2n+2)!=$

$(n+1)!^{n}\cdot(n+1)!\cdot\dfrac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!}=$

$(n+1)!^{n+1}\cdot\dfrac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!}=$

$(n+1)!^{n+1}\cdot\underbrace{(n+2)\cdot(n+3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n+2)}_{n+1\text{ times}}\geq$

$(n+1)!^{n+1}\cdot\underbrace{(n+2)\cdot(n+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+2)}_{n+1\text{ times}}=$

$(n+1)!^{n+1}\cdot(n+2)^{n+1}=$

$(n+2)!^{n+1}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 1):

> Assume (by contradiction)
>   $$2!⋅⋅⋅(2k)!(2k+2)!<((k+1)!)k(2k+2)!$$

Why would you assume that, you just showed the contrary one line above ?

Once you're here
$$2!\cdot\cdot\cdot (2k)!(2k+2)!\ge ((k+1)!)^k(2k+2)!$$
you just have to show that $((k+1)!)^k(2k+2)! \ge (k+2)!^{k+1}$.

$(k+2)!^{k+1} = (k+1)!^k \times (k+2)^k \times (k+2)!$ and $(k+2)^k \times (k+2)! \le (2k+2)!$ (because $k+2 < k+2+i$ for all $i$). Thus, you have your result.

Answer (score 0):

Define $S$ the wanted number. Then
$$
S=\prod_{i=1}^n (2i)!=\prod_{i=1}^n (2(n+1-i))!.
$$
Therefore, based on $a!b!\ge \max(a,b)!\ge \frac{a+b}{2}!$ whenever $a,b$ are integers with same parity, we conclude that
$$
S=\sqrt{\prod_{i=1}^n(2(n+1-i))!(2i)!}\ge \sqrt{\prod_{i=1}^n(n+1)!^2}=(n+1)!^n.
$$

Answer (score 0):

That is equivalent to:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\Gamma(2k+1) \geq n \log\Gamma(n+2) \tag{1}$$
that is a trivial inequality, since $\log\Gamma$ is a convex function, due to the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Also, because for odd $n$ we have
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!(n-1)!}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n+1)!(n-3)!}\cdot...\cdot\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)!0!}\cdot(n-1)!(n-3)!...2!\geq1.$$
For the even $n$ it's the similar.